# How to get latitude longitude from google map URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way by which I can find out the latitude and longitude from the google url using javacript?
I am developing a mobile application in android using phonegap.

**HTML code**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map</title>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 51.520838, -0.140261 );
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( "map_canvas" ), myOptions );
        }
    </script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <style>
        html {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #map_canvas { 
            height: 100%;
        }    
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

    <div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here latitude and longitude needs to be passed to the function in order to load the map. But I do not have it saved in my database for the app instead I have google map url. How can I get long,latitude from a google map url?

Answer (score 1):

**Get current Latitude and Longitude**

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

function onSuccess(position) {
  var current_lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var current_lng = position.coords.longitude;

}

function onError(error)
{
    alert(error)    
}
```